# Google Sign In from a Non-Activity Class

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin, google-authentication

I'm implementing a LoginManager that can handle the login with email, Facebook or Google. The first two ones are working correctly. My problem is that when I call this method from the `LoginManager`:

`context.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 0);`

The result is not retrieved to the overridden method: `onActivityResult()`, that is placed in the Fragment that makes the call to the `LoginManager`.
The variable context is passed as parameter from the Fragment to the `LoginManager`.

Comment: I have recently tackled the issue of logging into to multiple networks and have created a library for it. Check it out, maybe it will prove useful to you:
https://github.com/iFanie/Roguin

Comment: Only an activity gets a onActivityResult. Can you override it in the activity, and pass it back to the Fragment.

Comment: Ok, but my question is: how can I pass to LoginManager the right Activity where to return the result?

Comment: After years, I come back to this post and I state that this was a very stupid way to proceed.